# Node-webkit and google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, node-webkit

Trying to get Google Drive API to work in node-webkit.

When the auth message is sent, it is sent with an Origin of File:// which is rejected.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
?client_id=<some value>
&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
&immediate=true
&proxy=oauth2relay1232990068
&redirect_uri=postmessage
&origin=file://
&response_type=token
&state=1938150804|0.1319366391
&authuser=0
```

Not sure why it is sent that way from gapi - anyone know how to auth google drive from node-webkit?

Comment: My guess is that gapi wasn't written with node as a use case. My short suggestion is don't use it. You know what the URL needs to look like, so just call it directly and parse the JSON response.

Comment: I took your advice - it was easy enough to implement the REST desktop solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opted to bypass the API for oAuth and do it myself.

The user has to copy an auth code and paste it into my app - not first choice, but they only have to do it once and it is preferable to the (lack of) alternative.

Sharing the code for those interested:

When the user choose Google drive:

```
            window.open('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'
                    + 'client_id=<some value>'
                    + '&scope=<space delimited list of permissions>'
                    + '&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
                    + '&response_type=code');
```

This produces a popup that let's them Allow and presents them auth code.

When auth code is pasted into my app, I save it to DB and proceed with getting an access code, which I then save to DB:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    code: <authCode>,
                    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
                    redirect_uri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }
            }).error(function(data) {
                myObj.isAuth = false;
                if (cbFail) {
                    cbFail(data);
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                myObj.isAuth = true;
                <persist entire response>
                if (cbSuccess) {
                    cbSuccess();
                }
            });
```